# Smarty modifer/plugin to get a labels from an array

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

This is the example array I get sent from the CMS to Smarty.

```
[field] => Array
(
    [value] => 19
    [options] => Array
        (
            [labels] => Array
                (
                    [0] => --- Select ---
                    [1] => John
                    [2] => Mark
                    [3] => Luke
                    [4] => Philip
                )

            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 19
                    [4] => 17
                )

        )
```

So I would normally write `{$field.value}` or `{html_options values=$field.options.values output=$field.options.labels selected=$field.value}`

My question is how can I easily get the label from the value. I tried this: `{$field.options.labels[$field.value]}` but then realise this is just going to get the index of the array and not the value.

I know you could do this in a {foreach/if} but that is going to get messy in the template. Is there a way to write a plugin for this?

Comment: I'm not sure but something like this could work `{html_options values=array_combine(array_values($field.options.values),array_values($field.options.labels))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without foreach loop it can be done in one-liner:

```
{$field.options.labels[$field.value|array_search:$field.options.values]}
```

Or modifier:

```
function extractLabel($field){
    $idx = array_search($field['value'], $field['options']['values']);
    if($idx !== FALSE && isset($field['options']['labels'][$idx])){
        return $field['options']['labels'][$idx];       
    }
}

$smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'extractLabel', 'extractLabel');
```

tpl:

```
{$field|extractLabel}
```